# All commands produce an error

Tags: command-line

Just logged into new install of Ubuntu 14.04 as admin. Everytime I enter a basic command like LS, cd /usr/bin  anything, I get a  command process failed, error 253,  command not recognised. [see image]   any ideas. I am completely lost. Thx

image:  [image]

Comment: How do you log in - which command do you use?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy-paste the text, and use the formatting tools to make it look nice.

Answer (score 4):

Base on [this thread](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/177/t/19433041), I don't think you ssh-ed into Linux shell but rather some firewall management backend.

Comment: Hmm..  I am just going on the details I was provided. Let me go and verify that. That's not something I had considered.